# Kotlin annotation composed of other annotations

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I'm writing an android application in Kotlin and I'm using retrofit. Here I have **some** APIs that require `JWT` token in the header by the format : `"Authorization" : "Bearer <token>"`.
Now I can use the custom `@Header` annotation, but the problem is that it doesn't add the `Bearer` part and I want to do it in a clean way. The way I chose is to create an annotation. So I'm trying to create an annotation (e.g. `@JWT`) that receives the token as a parameter and prefixes "Bearer" to it, and then use the `@Header` annotation to pass it to retrofit:

```
fun myAPICall(@JWT("some token") val token): ...
```

I've tried using `okhttp` interceptor, but here is this: I want to know how could I define such an annotator and also in the case that not all my `Authorization` tokens have the mentioned format, this interceptor would not work or it would get really large.
I'm still trying to find the answer and if I find it, I will share it with you, but if you already know how to do it, I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me like interceptor would still be the most common way to do it. It is hard to think of an API that uses different formats of authorization tokens. If your API is indeed using different formats of tokens, you may be wanting to redesign it

Comment: Actually I'm not sure whether if the API has different formats of tokens or not, but I want to get deeper into kotlin annotations and I thought this might be a good opportunity to do so. Still trying to find a way :D